# Use python to output image from cx_oracle blob

Tags: python, flask, cx-oracle

I have stored images in a oracle table within a BLOB column. I use to read and output an image and write data using JAVA. I would like to do the same (getting my image and distributing it) with python. I am using Flask framework and cx_Oracle.

I manage to get my BLOB content into my application but I am not sure how to generate an image from that.

I know that in **Java** i used :

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
IOUtils.copy( new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.getContent()),out);
out.flush();
```

where doc.getContent() is my BLOB content.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data and just need to get it to an image file on disk you can write it directly to a file opened for writing in binary mode.

```
import cx_oracle

sql = 'select img_fld from img_table where id=1234'
imagePath = './output/image.png'

conn = cx_oracle.connect('your_connection_string')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)

#assuming one row of image data is returned
row = cursor.fetchone()
imageBlob = row[0]

#open a new file in binary mode
imageFile = open(imagePath,'wb')

#write the data to the file
imageFile.write(imageBlob.read())

#closing the file flushes it to disk
imageFile.close()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

If you need a "file-like" object without writing to disk you can use the cStringIO module to create in-memory buffers.  https://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

Comment: ig got error `imageFile.write(imageBlob)`
`TypeError: must be string or buffer, not cx_Oracle.LOB`

Comment: @asdfme123 you have missed `.read()`. Use `imageFile.write(imageBlob.read())` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using Flask and your help :

```
@app.route('/_photo/')
def gripur():

    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("*****","****",make_dsn_tns(get_config_string()))
    curs = conn.cursor()
    #find photo
    document=curs.execute('select myblob from mytable where id=34234')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    imageBlob = row[0]

    blob= imageBlob.read()
    response = make_response(blob)
    response.headers["Content-type"] = "image/jpeg"
    conn.close()

    return response
```