# How to Export Multiple BLOB Data, Each To Their Respective Filename using Python

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-s3, blob

You have an Oracle Database Table containing BLOB data and a column which keeps name of the file for that BLOB Data. You want that each BLOB data is saved to Physical Files with names as stored in "File Name" Column. Please help me to do in Python.

### Prerequisite:

Consider a sample data as:

```
Table1
---------
filename        FileContent
myfile1.pdf      BLOB1
myfile2.pdf      BLOB2
myfile2.jpg      BLOB3
```

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? Please show it. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875994/3061852) to a similar question.

Comment: Here's the cx_Oracle doc on LOBs: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html and here's an example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py  The rest is just looping over each row and printing out the LOB in that row.

Comment: import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

conn=cx_Oracle.connect(user="xxxx",password="xxxx",dsn="localhost:1521/xe?expire_time=20")
print(conn.version)

cur=conn.cursor()
sql_create="""(select EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,SALARY,DEPT_ID from emp)"""
a=cur.execute(sql_create)
row=cur.fetchall()
print (row)
for i in row:
    try:
        
        with open(i[0],'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(i[1])
            outfile.close()
    except:
        pass

Comment: When I run this code in AWS EC2 instance ,I am getting error - cx_Oracle.DataBaseError: ORA-12170:TNS:Connect timeout occurred. Can anyone help with this?